# Regex to match print function usages

Tags: python, string, parsing

I am trying to delete all print usages in code, and for that I'm using regex to find the usages, but can't work my mind around it. I'm using the following regex expression:
`(print(\.*))`

But then the first `print` is only found in this piece of code:

```
class Dummy:
    __dummy: int = 0
    def get_dummy(self) -> int:
        print("abc")
        print()
        do_print()
        a = """
           print()
            """
        return self.__dummy
```

When the correct result should be a match in the first, second and fourth `print` calls.
Could somebody give me a clue on how to fix the regex expr.?

Thanks!

I have tried using the regex expression previously mentioned and many others, but can't get around it.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/97cBmw/1

Comment: The above regex works for provided example but it should be noted that regex is not well suited for matching balanced parentheneses, so any more complex statement including print might break the expression.

Comment: Are you sure youre using the correct regex search function? Some find only one match whereas other find multiple. The above regex finds the correct `print`s with brackets but your regex should also have multiple matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r'\bprint\s*\(.+?\)?'
```

Above should work for you.

- `\b` - matches the word only (word boundary). It won't match the `do_print`
- `\s*` - matches 0 or any spaces.
- `\(.+?\)?` - matches the parentheses plus any text in between if any.